# ViewPort3D: How to create a WPF Object (Cube) with text on it from Code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, viewport3d, helix-3d-toolkit

I want to draw a set of 3D-Cubes, each Cube should display a name and also should have its own  event handler when the cube is selected.

Is it possible to implement it using code behind or xaml binding?

Comment: Which aspect are you struggling with? Are you able to draw a cube? Also have a look at the Helix 3D Toolkit (http://helixtoolkit.codeplex.com) if you are doing any work with WPF 3D.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To draw a 3D cube from code behind I would use the Helix3D toolkit CubeVisual3D. However if you want to stick with stock WPF 3D elements it is fairly simple to implement.

start here to Learn about Text in 3D enviroments http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33893/WPF-Creation-of-Text-Labels-for-3D-Scene which will guide you through two different approaches to adding Text to a 3D image and I find very helpful.

For a cube Just use a RectangleVisual3D object Something like this.

```
    RectangleVisual3D myCube = new RectangleVisual3D();
    myCube.Origin = new Point3D(0, 0, 0); //Set this value to whatever you want your Cube Origen to be.
    myCube.Width = 5; //whatever width you would like.
    myCube.Length = 5; //Set Length = Width
    myCube.Normal = new Vector3D(0, 1, 0); // if you want a cube that is not at some angle then use a vector in the direction of an axis such as this one or <1,0,0> and <0,0,1>
    myCube.LengthDirection = new Vector3D(0, 1, 0); //This will depend on the orientation of the cube however since it is equilateral just set it to the same thing as normal.
    myCube.Material = new DiffuseMaterial(Brushes.Red); // Set this with whatever you want or just set the myCube.Fill Property with a brush type.
```

Too add the event handler I believe you must add the Handler to the Viewport3D. Something of this nature should work.

```
    public Window1()
    {
    InitializeComponent();
    this.mainViewport.MouseDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(mainViewport_MouseDown);
    this.mainViewport.MouseUp += new MouseButtonEventHandler(mainViewport_MouseUp);
    }
```

Then Add this function

```
    ModelVisual3D GetHitResult(Point location)
    {
    HitTestResult result = VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(mainViewport, location);
    if(result != null && result.VisualHit is ModelVisual3D)
    {
    ModelVisual3D visual = (ModelVisual3D)result.VisualHit;
    return visual;
    }

    return null;
    }
```

Then Add in the Event Handlers

```
    void mainViewport_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
    Point location = e.GetPosition(mainViewport);
    ModelVisual3D result = GetHitResult(location);
    if(result == null)
    {
    return;
    }
    //Do Stuff Here
    }

    void mainViewport_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
    Point location = e.GetPosition(mainViewport);
    ModelVisual3D result = GetHitResult(location);
    if(result == null)
    {
    return;
    }
    //Do Stuff Here
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the link for the rendering problem. Your solution for clicking did not work out for me as I needed the GeometryModel3D. Managed to do it using http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpf3d/archive/2009/05/18/3d-hit-testing.aspx and then retrieving the Model via GeometryModel3D hitgeo = rayMeshResult.ModelHit as GeometryModel3D; Just in case someone has the same problem :)