# Helix - click coordinates on object inside HelixViewport3D

Tags: c#, wpf, onclick, helix-3d-toolkit

I would like to know the coordinates of the point in the HelixViewport3D where I clicking.

My task is:
1) RectangleVisual3D as some surface.
2) Clicking on this surface adding 3d-object under mouse pointer.

I found [=>this<=](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11615519/viewport3d-how-to-create-a-wpf-object-cube-with-text-on-it-from-code-behind), but could not develop the idea further.

Thanks for help :)